# Running 'wc' using execvp() recognizes /home/usr/foo.txt but not ~/foo.txt

Tags: c, command, exec

I have a program where I want to run the command `wc` using execvp().

The important bits are here:

```
char *argvNew[5];
argvNew[0] = "wc";
argvNew[1] = "/home/user/foo.txt";
argvNew[2] = NULL;
execvp(argvNew[0], arvgNew);
```

This works just fine and the terminal displays the output from `wc`. However, when I change the line to:

```
argvNew[1] = "~/foo.txt"
```

I get this error in the terminal:

```
wc: '~/foo.txt': No such file or directory
```

Running `wc ~/foo.txt` directly from the terminal behaves exactly as running `wc /home/user/foo.txt`. Why does `execvp` have an issue with the `~/` part?

Comment: The shell expands `~/foo.txt` for you before running the command. You therefore have to do that expansion if you want it to work — or use a shell to do the expansion for you. `execvp` has no problem with `~`; there simply isn't a directory called `~` in the current directory (and therefore there isn't a file called `foo.txt` in the non-existent directory).  It's not all that hard to write the code to do the job (though doing it properly per POSIX requires attention to detail — see [Tilde expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01)).

Comment: `~` only expands in the *shell* AFAIK. So it will not expand in a custom [tag:c] program. I mean, `program ~/xxx` in the shell will expand `~` and not `program`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tilde (`~`) expansion is done/understood by shells only - it's not expanded in C programs. So `execvp` attempts to interpret `~` as part of the filename (argument to `wc`).

What you can do is get the `HOME` directory value using `getenv` and prefix it with the filename (e.g., using `snprintf`).

Answer (score 1):

When you type a file name such as `~/foo.txt` at the command line, the shell expands it for you before running the command. You therefore have to do that expansion in your C code if you want it to work — or use a shell to do the expansion for you. Neither the `execvp()` function nor the `wc` command has any problem with `~`; there simply isn't a directory called `~` in the current directory (and therefore there isn't a file called `foo.txt` in the non-existent directory).

It's not all that hard to write the code to do the job (though doing it properly per POSIX requires attention to detail — see [Tilde expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01)).

However, there are also standard POSIX functions that can help and do that job, notably [`wordexp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html).  Although the standard doesn't explicitly mention tilde expansion, it does mention `WRDE_NOCMD` to suppress [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03), so it is supposed to do a thorough job and tilde expansion should be included in a conforming implementation.

Here is some simple test code exercising the function:

```
#include "stderr.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wordexp.h>

/*
int wordexp(const char *restrict words, wordexp_t *restrict pwordexp,
       int flags);
void wordfree(wordexp_t *pwordexp);
*/

static void do_wordexp(const char *name)
{
    wordexp_t wx = { 0 };
    if (wordexp(name, &wx, WRDE_NOCMD) != 0)
        err_remark("Failed to expand word [%s]\n", name);
    else
    {
        printf("Expansion of [%s]:\n", name);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < wx.we_wordc; i++)
            printf("%zu: [%s]\n", i+1, wx.we_wordv[i]);
        wordfree(&wx);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    if (argc <= 1)
        do_wordexp("~/.profile");
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
            do_wordexp(argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here are a couple of sample runs (program `wexp19` built from `wexp19.c`):

```
$ wexp19
Expansion of [~/.profile]:
1: [/Users/jonathanleffler/.profile]
$ wexp19 '~informix/bin/oninit' '~/bin/rfmt'  '~/bin/al ~/bin/b?' '~/bin/f?' '$IXD/bin/onstat' ' ~/bin/ow '
Expansion of [~informix/bin/oninit]:
1: [/Users/informix/bin/oninit]
Expansion of [~/bin/rfmt]:
1: [/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/rfmt]
Expansion of [~/bin/al ~/bin/b?]:
1: [/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/al]
2: [/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/bk]
Expansion of [~/bin/f?]:
1: [/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/fd]
2: [/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/fl]
3: [/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/fm]
Expansion of [$IXD/bin/onstat]:
1: [/opt/informix/12.10.FC6/bin/onstat]
Expansion of [ ~/bin/ow ]:
1: [/Users/jonathanleffler/bin/ow]
$
```

Note in particular the result of expanding the quote-enclosed command line argument `'~/bin/al ~/bin/b?'`; it is split and the words are separately expanded.  The next to last argument expands the environment variable `$IXD` from my environment, too, and the last example shows blanks are removed.  The single quotes on the command line are necessary to stop the shell from doing what I want to demonstrate `wordexp()` doing.

Tests run on a Mac running macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra, and using GCC 8.2.0.  YMMV!