# excevp does not take over child process (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, exec, parent-child, child-process

I am trying to run the stockfish engine as a child process in my code. I want to use fork() and execvp() to do this. I temporarily add the location of the stockfish executable to my PATH by running the command

`export PATH="~/Apps/stockfish_15_linux_x64_avx2:$PATH"`

And I checked to make sure this is added to PATH by running `echo $PATH`. I can also run the stockfish executable from any directory during my current terminal session, so this part seems to be working. What I am having trouble with is running stockfish from another executable using execvp.

I have the following code that reproduces the bug.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void ) { 
    const char* argv[] = {"stockfish_15_x64_avx2", "d", NULL};
    int pid = fork(); 

    if (pid < 0) { 
        printf("Failed to fork");
    }

    else if (pid == 0){ 
        execvp(argv[0], (char* const*)argv); 
    }

    sleep( 1 ); 



    
    printf("Finished executing the parent process \n"
    " -- The child won't get here -- you will only see this once. \n");

    return 0;
}
```

the `d` command in stockfish displays a diagram of the current position. This would be the start position in this case. But instead of getting this diagram, the output I get is simply

```
 Finished executing the parent process 
 -- The child won't get here -- you will only see this once. 
Finished executing the parent process 
 -- The child won't get here -- you will only see this once.
```

What this tells me is that execvp is not actually taking over the child process. When I change the arguments to a more generic command like `argv[] = {"ls", "-a", NULL}` then the code works as expected. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: If your execvp is returning, you can add error handling to it. Maybe the errno will shed some light on what went wrong.

Comment: Did you run the program in the same terminal session where you checked the PATH?  In the PATH variable you need to put just the directory, not the executable name.  You need to set the PATH in `~/.bashrc` to have it in every bash session.  Finally, why don't you call `waitpid()` instead of `sleep()`?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/52084867/1216776

Comment: @Ale Yes, I used the same terminal session, and I only added the directory. I didn't want to add the directory to PATH permanently, although I suppose I could set it then remove it later. And you are correct, `waitpid()` seems to be the way to go in this case, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was starting to use waitpid to do some error handling, when I had a hunch that the underscores in the executable name were somehow the problem. And sure enough, when I renamed the executable to 'stockfish15' everything works as intended.

The code now looks like this

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void ) { 
    const char* argv[] = {"stockfish15", "d", NULL};
    pid_t pid = fork(); 
    if (pid == -1) { 
        printf("Failed to fork");
    }
    else if (pid == 0) { 
        execvp(argv[0], (char* const*) argv);
    }

    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0); 

    if (WIFEXITED(status)) { 
        printf("child terminated normally\n");
    }

    else {printf("exevp error\n");}
    
    
    printf("Finished executing the parent process \n"
    " -- The child won't get here -- you will only see this once. \n");

    return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
Stockfish 15 by the Stockfish developers (see AUTHORS file)

 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | r | n | b | q | k | b | n | r | 8
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | p | p | p | p | p | p | p | p | 7
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 6
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 5
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 4
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 3
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | P | P | P | P | P | P | P | P | 2
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | R | N | B | Q | K | B | N | R | 1
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h

Fen: rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1
Key: 8F8F01D4562F59FB
Checkers: 
child terminated normally
Finished executing the parent process 
 -- The child won't get here -- you will only see this once.
```

Still, I'd like to know the explanation for why this is happening.

Comment: The name is well below length limits and the underscore has nothing special, but a simple name is easier to type.  About `waitpid()`, note that you may be calling it with pid equal to 0 or -1 (those special values are handled correctly, though).